# Selenium TestnNg - where should AssertAll() be placed in the test

Tags: java, annotations, testng

I am working on Page Object Model framework in the Selenium -TestNG using Java in Eclipse IDE. I have my base class, pages and test classes ready. In my test, I am using SoftAssert class as I want my test to continue even when they fail. In the end I do SoftAssert.assertAll().

Everything works fine.

But ideally where should assertAll method be executed?

1. In the last test method (@Test) which is going to get executed in that class?
   2)AfterClass
   3)AfterSuite

Comment: Is @AfterTest appropriate as it will be executed only once after the test suite execution is over?

Answer (score 0):

As per ur comment @AfterTest ? what you meant by @AfterTest ?

@BeforeTest and @AfterTest are respective to test `(<test> ... </test>)` in testng.xml file

simply use SoftAssert softAssertion= new SoftAssert(); at start of @Test and softAssertion.assertAll(); at end

```
@Test
public void softAssert(){
    SoftAssert softAssertion= new SoftAssert();
    //..............
    //..............
    softAssertion.assertAll();
}
```

go through doc to learn more on testng https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html